# Differentiation along directions for maps on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, separable-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $\ell^2 \equiv \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ denote the space of square-summable real sequences.

Let $f \colon \ell^2 \to \ell^2$. Let $f_v(x) := \langle v, f(x) \rangle$.

Suppose there exists a continuous linear operator $D_x \colon \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ such that that for each unit vector $v \in \ell^2$,
$$
\big|f_v(x + h) - \{f_v(x) + \langle D_x h, v \rangle\} \big| = o\big(\|h\|\big), 
\quad \mbox{as}~h \to 0.
$$

Does it then imply that $D_x$ is the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $x$? If instead we restrict to basis vectors $v = e_j$,  $j = 1, 2, \ldots$, does this still hold?

In general, it would also be useful to know of a reference where one can find such basic results regarding differentiability of functions on $\ell^2$ (or equivalently, over a separable Hilbert space).

Comment: Shouldn't it be $...+ \langle D_x h,v\rangle$ instead of $...+ \langle D_x v,h\rangle$?

Comment: Ah you're right. (I had in mind the gradient of $f$ which is the adjoint of $D_x$)

Answer (score 0):

At least the restriction to basis vectors seems to fail: Set
$$
f:l^2 \to l^2, \quad f(x)=\left(\frac{\cos(2^kx_k)}{k}\right)_{k=1}^\infty,
$$
consider differentiability at $0$ and set $D_0x:=0$ $(x \in l^2)$.

Now $f_{e_k}(x)= \cos(2^kx_k)/k$ and for $h \not=0$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{\|h\|}|f_{e_k}(h)-f_{e_k}(0)-\langle D_0h,e_k \rangle|= \frac{1}{\|h\|}| \frac{\cos(2^kh_k)}{k}-\frac{1}{k}| 
$$
$$
\le \frac{1}{|h_k|}| \frac{\cos(2^kh_k)}{k}-\frac{1}{k}| \to 0 \quad  (\|h\| \to 0).
$$
Note for the inequality above that we have $\le 0$ if $h_k=0$.

On the other hand $f$ is not totally differentiable in $0$: For $h \not=0$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{\|h\|}\|f(h)-f(0)- D_0h\| = \frac{1}{\|h\|} \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\frac{\cos(2^kh_k)}{k}-\frac{1}{k}|^2\right)^{1/2} \quad =:g(h)
$$
Inserting $h^{(n)}:=\frac{\pi}{2^n} e_n$ (note that $\|h^{(n)}\| \to 0$) yields
$$
g(h^{(n)})=\frac{2^n}{\pi}|\frac{\cos(\pi)}{n}-\frac{1}{n}|=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n\pi} \to \infty \quad (n \to \infty).
$$

Comment: I'm a little confused, doesn't $\cos(x)/x$ diverge in the limit as $x \to 0$? If so how do you make the conclusion above "note for the inequality above that we have..."

Comment: We have $|\cos(2^k x)-1|/|x| \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, since $|\cos(2^k x)-1|/|x|$ is the absolut value of the difference quotient of $x \mapsto \cos(2^k x)$ at $0$. The limit is the absolut value of the derivative of $x \mapsto \cos(2^k x)$ at $0$ which is $|-2^k\sin(2^k 0)|=0$. In the inequality  $\|h\| \ge |h_k|$ is used. If $h \not=0$ it can happen that $h_k=0$. But this is no problem since for $x=0$ we have  $|\cos(2^k x)-1| = 0$.